# Any way to prevent "resource" warnings on Mock implementations?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, compiler-warnings

This goes in the category of a minor, but constant, annoyance.  I am using Eclipse IDE. It very helpfully marks warnings for various coding problems, including:

> Potential resource leak: 'connection' may not be closed

This can be a very helpful warning when you are dealing with real resource objects, so I like to leave Eclipse configured to show the warning.  However, when dealing with Mock objects in unit tests (in this example, it is a unit test friendly implementation of the `java.sql.Connection` interface.), it is a nuisance.  The only way I know of to remove the warning is to add the `@SuppressWarnings("resource")` annotation to the code which is referencing the object.  Unfortunately this has to be done wherever the Mock class is used, which means a lot of repetition for a frequently used Mock class.

Is there any class level annotation that I can put on the Mock class to prevent the warning in the first place?  Or is there some other means for preventing the warning for classes which don't really have any resource leaks?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your version of Java (you need java 7, released mid-2011), you could use the try-with block.  It's a nice feature in that it also scopes your variables, not letting them hang on longer than they're needed.

Answer (score 0):

I Have your same problem.
The `@SuppressWarnings("resource")` annotation can work at TYPE level, so I annotated the entire test class in which the resource is mocked.

This is a sample:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public class BatchDaoTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private BatchDao cut;

    @Mock
    private Connection con;

...
```

I Know it is not the best solution (because it can hide real problems), but it's the only workaround I found so far.